What is the name of this psychological thriller movie?
The movie involves a darkroom (you know, the ones where photographs are developed). 
The protagonist is an old man with mental issues who befriends a small child (and his parents) in a shop. He then somehow ends up kidnapping the parents (definitely the mother, I am not sure about the father though). After the kidnap ends,the man is put in a mental institution (or a prison, I'm not sure). The ending scene shows a photo of him and the family, looking happy together. This ending could be interpreted in two ways: 
1) The old man imagines becoming friends with the child and the family again.
2) The old man is forgiven by the family.
I have searched for this using the term "Darkroom", but could not find anything, so I guess the movie goes by another name.
Useful information : I am 99% sure the movie was produced between 2000 and 2010.

This must be 2002's One Hour Photo starring Robin Williams. From Wikipedia:
Seymour "Sy" Parrish (Robin Williams) is a photo technician at SavMart's one-hour photo developing clinic... His favorite customers are the Yorkin family: husband Will, wife Nina, and their son Jake...
Sy secretly makes his own copies of the Yorkins' photos from the film negatives and then puts them on a wall in his apartment in a massive collage. He fantasizes about being a member of their family and sharing in the love he assumes they feel...
Sy discovers that Will is having an extramarital affair... Sy confronts Will and Maya during a rendezvous in their hotel room. Armed with a knife and a camera, Sy forces the lovers to pose naked in sexual positions while he takes pictures. After the confrontation, Sy discovers that the police have arrived at the hotel...
The film closes with an "imagined" family picture of the Yorkins with Will's arm around a smiling Sy.

Great (and creepy) movie!

Robin Williams isn't much of a chameleon - you pretty much know it's him when he's on screen (contrast with Gary Oldman). I'm fascinated that the asker didn't remember that detail of the movie (that it starred Williams).
